# Regex to match start of string or space or comma

Tags: c#, regex

I am looking to match a postcode using the following regex:

```
(GIR ?0AA|[A-PR-UWYZ]([0-9]{1,2}|([A-HK-Y][0-9]([0-9ABEHMNPRV-Y])?)|[0-9][A-HJKPS-UW]) ?[0-9][ABD-HJLNP-UW-Z]{2})
```

I am trying to parse an address from an HTML document and as such I only want to match nodes that start with a postcode or contain a postcode that is preceded by a space or comma.  Otherwise there are too many false positives e.g. matching colours (preceded by #).

I need to amend the regex to either find the postcode with no preceding characters or a space or comma immediately preceding it and any number of characters before this.  How can I do this?

For example, I would want to match:

```
IP14 2PL
1 The street, ipswich, IP14 2PL
1 The street, ipswich,IP14 2PL
```

BUT NOT

```
https://t.co/ip142plzruc
```

Comment: Could you provide input and desire output ?

Comment: "I am trying to parse an address from an HTML document". Note the OP isn't regexing the HTML (I [hope](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1901857)), just the extracted content, so don't downvote based purely on that statement :)

Comment: I'm not regexing the HTML, I am parsing the HTML and matching the innertext of certain nodes to a regex. Why the downvote?

Comment: @Rhumborl don't assume that the guy who comment is the guy who downvote ;)

Comment: @Thomas sorry, don't get you. I posted that comment before any voting had occurred, to stop a reasonable question being unnecessarily massacred. When I first read the question, I instinctively thought, yeah here's another one - then I actually read the regex and realised it's not.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just add this in front of your expression:

```
(?:^|[, ])
```

It will make mandatory to have a space or a comma before or it begins a line.

Comment: This doesn't match the 1st case above, where the postcode is the start of the string

Comment: @Macros: Sorry, I missed that constraint Answer edited.